# Unable to create new text file using PYTHON

Tags: python

I'm new to Python... and trying to create a new text file.
But I am getting an error message as ErrNo 13 Permission denied 'newfile.txt'. Attached my code.

```
raghu ="Hello world"
print(raghu)

name = input("What's your name? ") 
print("Nice to meet you " + name + "!")

file = open("newfile.txt", "w")
file.write("Nice to meet you " + name + "!")
```

Comment: What is your working dir? Have you checked if you have a writing permisions in said dir?

Comment: Permission denied could mean that the file already exists and you don't have write access to it, or you don't have write access to your current directory.  How are you running the program?

Comment: By the way, you probably want to terminate your `write()` with a newline, for example `"!\n"`.  Also, it is good programming practice to do a `.close()` at the end to release resources.

Comment: check whether your `newfile.txt` opened in any editor if it is opened then `close` it, and then try again

Answer (score -3):

Add the code file.close() after your file.write() statement.
If a file is not closed, then all access to the file will be prevented.  Closing your IDE would also help if file.close() doesn't work so you can start from the beginning.

Comment: using `with open('newfile.txt','w') as file` would be better since it will automatically deal with closing the file.

Comment: I thought the with statement would be unnecessarily complicated.  I know I had a slight learning curve understanding with.  Not sure if that why i got downvoted.